# MediaCodec with Surface input: Producing chunked output

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

I'm trying to produce short sequential mp4 files from CameraPreview data via `MediaCodec.createInputSurface()`. However, recreating the `MediaCodec` and it's associated Surface requires stopping the Camera to allow another call to `mCamera.setPreviewTexture(...)`. This delay results in an unacceptable amount of dropped frames.

Therefore I need to generate the `CODEC_CONFIG` and `END_OF_STREAM` data periodically without recreating the input Surface, and thus having to call `mCamera.setPreviewTexture(...)`. Is this possible assuming the `MediaFormat` is unchanged?

(I'm adapting fadden's [CameraToMpegTest](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/CameraToMpegTest.java.txt) example. My complete code is [here](https://github.com/OnlyInAmerica/HWEncoderExperiments/blob/chunked2/HWEncoderExperiments/src/main/java/net/openwatch/hwencoderexperiments/ChunkedHWRecorder.java))

**Unsuccessful attempts:**

Calling `MediaCodec.signalEndOfInputStream()`, draining the `MediaCodec`, and then calling `MediaCodec.flush()` between chunks produces an `IllegalStateException` on the 2nd call to `MediaCodec.signalEndOfInputStream()`.

Calling `MediaCodec.signalEndOfInputStream()`, draining the `MediaCodec`, and then calling `MediaCodec.stop(); MediaCodec.configure(...), MediaCodec.start()` between chunks without again calling `MediaCodec.createInputSurface()` produces the following error:

```
    09-30 13:12:49.889  17638-17719/x.xx.xxxx E/Surface﹕ queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -19
09-30 13:12:49.889  17638-17719/x.xx.xxxx E/IMGSRV﹕ :0: UnlockPostBuffer: Failed to queue buffer 0x592e1e70
09-30 13:12:49.889  17638-17719/x.xx.xxxx E/CameraToMpegTest﹕ Encoding loop exception!
09-30 13:12:49.889  17638-17719/x.xx.xxxx W/System.err﹕ java.lang.RuntimeException: eglSwapBuffers: EGL error: 0x300b
09-30 13:12:49.896  17638-17719/x.xx.xxxx W/System.err﹕ at x.xx.xxxx.ChunkedHWRecorder$CodecInputSurface.checkEglError(ChunkedHWRecorder.java:731)
09-30 13:12:49.896  17638-17719/x.xx.xxxx W/System.err﹕ at x.xx.xxxx.ChunkedHWRecorder$CodecInputSurface.swapBuffers(ChunkedHWRecorder.java:713)
09-30 13:12:49.896  17638-17719/x.xx.xxxx W/System.err﹕ at x.xx.xxxx.ChunkedHWRecorder.startRecording(ChunkedHWRecorder.java:164)
09-30 13:12:49.896  17638-17719/x.xx.xxxx W/System.err﹕ at x.xx.xxxx.HWRecorderActivity$CameraToMpegWrapper.run(HWRecorderActivity.java:76)
09-30 13:12:49.896  17638-17719/x.xx.xxxx W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

**Solved** Thanks fadden. The complete solution source is [here](https://github.com/OnlyInAmerica/HWEncoderExperiments/blob/chunked2/HWEncoderExperiments/src/main/java/net/openwatch/hwencoderexperiments/ChunkedHWRecorder.java).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `signalEndOfInputStream()` call updates the state of various layers in the MediaCodec stack.  You can get some sense of what operations are valid from the comments above the tests in [MediaCodecTest](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/jb-mr2-release/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts/MediaCodecTest.java), but by and large the behavior of MediaCodec is simply not defined for "unusual" uses.

So you have to look at the code.  The lifetime of the input surface is tied to that of the [OMXNodeInstance](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/jb-mr2-release/media/libstagefright/include/OMXNodeInstance.h); it's represented by [GraphicBufferSource](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/jb-mr2-release/media/libstagefright/omx/GraphicBufferSource.h).  Once you signal EOS, the GraphicBufferSource will ignore additional frames (see [line 426](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/jb-mr2-release/media/libstagefright/omx/GraphicBufferSource.cpp)).  There's no way to reset the EOS flag without tearing down the GraphicBufferSource, but when you do that it disconnects the buffer queue that underlies the Surface.

So I don't think you're going to be able to stop/restart the MediaCodec and continue to use the Surface.

However... you shouldn't need to.  CameraToMpegTest routes the camera preview to a SurfaceTexture, and then renders the texture onto the encoder's input surface with GLES.  The SurfaceTexture is decoupled from the encoder and shouldn't need to change.  I think what needs to change is CodecInputSurface, which calls `eglCreateWindowSurface()` with the Surface from the MediaCodec to tell GLES where to draw.  If you add a new "update Surface" API there (destroy old EGLSurface, create new EGLSurface, eglMakeCurrent), and call it whenever you spin up a new MediaCodec, I *think* it'll all just work.

**Update to address comments**:

It's important that you only change the `EGLSurface`.  The `checkAndUpdateEglStateLocked()` function in [GLConsumer.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/jb-mr2-release/libs/gui/GLConsumer.cpp) checks to make sure the `EGLDisplay` and `EGLContext` don't change once they've been set.  You can't call `release()`/`eglSetup()` in CodecInputSurface because it changes the `EGLContext`.  You just want to destroy and recreate the `EGLSurface`.

Comment: Thanks tons! `CodecInputSurface.updateSurface(newSurface)` does `release(); mSurface = newSurface; eglSetup();`. I then call `mMediaCodec.start(); mInputSurface.makeCurrent(); STextureRender.surfaceCreated();`. I get `E/GLConsumer﹕ checkAndUpdateEglState: invalid current EGLContext` on the next call to `SurfaceTexture.updateTexImage()`. Any ideas? [nutshell](http://pastebin.com/znwvz6wB). [Full code](https://github.com/OnlyInAmerica/HWEncoderExperiments/blob/chunked2/HWEncoderExperiments/src/main/java/net/openwatch/hwencoderexperiments/ChunkedHWRecorder.java). I'll keep at it.

Comment: I need to buy you a beer. I also had to remove my call to `STextureRender.surfaceCreated()` after each call to `CodecInputSurface.updateSurface(newSurface)`.

Comment: Oh right, that would change the texture ID out from under SurfaceTexture.