# Record a View in Android

Tags: android, video, view

Is it possible to record the contents of any View the same way that recording the screen is possible? Does the media projection API have a way to project a specific View?

Comment: "Does the media projection API have a way to project a specific View?" -- no, because it works at the system level, well below where you deal with things like `View`. "Is it possible to record the contents of any View the same way that recording the screen is possible?" -- if by record you mean an MP4, not really. If the `View` is not moving, use the media projection APIs to record the whole screen, then crop the resulting video to only show the portion that you need.

Comment: Interesting idea. The view can be moved and scaled unfortunately. If the View is a surface view does that change anything?

Comment: You might be able to basically implement a "tee" and have the content sent both to the surface and to something else to record a file. I suggest that you poke around [fadden's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/294248/fadden?tab=answers), such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27824250/115145) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25086739/115145) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19105030/115145) for ideas.